# on click does not work after inserting dynamic HTML with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I am trying to achieve code reusability by whenever a div is clicked, it gives out the div's `numberDiv` attribute. It works on the first default div that has a class `divClassSelector`, but I have some other js code that whenever you press the button "+1 Div", inserts another div. Then, when I try to alert the newly created div's numberDiv attribute, it does not work. I am assuming that it is because the newly created div did not exist in the DOM when the page was first loaded, therefore it cannot find the new div. I could be wrong though.

Does anybody know a workaround to this issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
//HTML
...
<body>
    <div class="divClassSelector" numberDiv="1"></div>
    <button id="plusOneDiv">+1 Div</button>
</body>
...

//My JS:

//Code to alert the div's numberDiv attribute value
$(".divClassSelector").on("click", function(){
    var numberDiv = $(this).attr("numberDiv");
    alert(numberDiv);
});

//Code to insert another div
var count = 2;
$("#plusOneDiv").click(function(){
    $(body).append(<div class="divClassSelector" numberDiv="'+count+'">');
    count++;
});
```

Thank you for your help in advance and cheers!

---

UPDATE 1:

Does anyone know how to instead on clicking the div, trigger an event that is triggered by having the "focus" on a form input field, that is, when you click on it and are interacting with it. I tried by using the "focus" method, but it kept alerting the same thing over and over, until I closed the tab, then I could escape from the alert infinite loop. Thanks!

Comment: use `data-div-no="count"` for div attribute its html standard

Comment: you can also use `$(body).delegate('.className', 'click', function() {//your code goes here});` or follow this link https://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: check for console you might have error in your code. probably `$(body).append(<div class="divClassSelector" numberDiv="'+count+'">');` you are missing `'<div`

Comment: Don't use `alert()` inside a `focus()` handler. Your focus handler fires, which pops up the alert, which fires the `blur()` event. You close the alert, which fires the `focus()` event, which pops up the alert, and you have an infinite loop. If you simply avoid using an `alert()`, binding events to `focus()` will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all add this '$' to your code: --$(this).attr("numberDiv");--

```
$(".divClassSelector").on("click", function(){
var numberDiv = $(this).attr("numberDiv");
alert(numberDiv);
});
```

Also change your click function to

```
$(document).on("click",".divClassSelector", function(){
var numberDiv = $(this).attr("numberDiv");
alert(numberDiv);
});
```

Comment: I have it there, actually I forgot to put it. Still doesnt work

Comment: ok , then use this click function , in replacement to that.

Comment: `.on(".divClassSelector","click",` suppose to be `.on("click",".divClassSelector",`

Comment: Thank you it did work. Could you elaborate on the Update 1 of my post if possible? Thanks!

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali , It also works.

Comment: @RohitArora : How you know it work?? 1st paramter should be events, not selector.. See doc here. https://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali Yours function  will work with jquery 1.7.3+ , but mine will work on jquery 1.4.3+ . This is the difference bro. You can use any way you want .

Comment: @RohitArora Can you give jsfiddle link to me, wanna see how it works on v1.4.3.. Because what i see on doc, the .on() method was added at v1.7 .

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali Dont have much time to create a fiddle , but iwill try .  Read this : https://api.jquery.com/live/ , you will get it here . Because previously it was .live() event in jquery .

Comment: Yes i know that one. And selector that you make above is .delegate() way, not the .on() way. New comers will confuses, and always use new version of code since the older will deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on('click', '.divClassSelector', function(){
var numberDiv = $(this).attr("numberDiv");
alert(numberDiv);
});
```

or

```
$('body').on('click', '.divClassSelector', function () {...})
```

you forgot `$`

```
var numberDiv = (this).attr("numberDiv");
```

to

```
 var numberDiv = $(this).attr("numberDiv");
```

Comment: I have it there, actually I forgot to put it. Still doesnt work

Comment: did u try using `$(document).on('click', '.divClassSelector', function(){`

Comment: Thank you it did work. Could you elaborate on the Update 1 of my post if possible? Thanks!

Comment: @JackGal approve the answer then